# Double "<" when creating php tag in Sublime Text 3

Tags: php, ide, editor, sublimetext3

When I open php tag

```
<php
```

and press enter, I'm ending up with

```
<<?php
?>
```

How to explain to Sublime that I don't need extra "<" at the beginning?

I can write

```
<?p
```

and press enter but then tag is not closed. I want to stay with 
`<php` and just edit somehow the result so that I don't have extra "<"

Comment: write only `php` and press `tab`

Comment: I really like "enter" using solutions in Sublime, so I was thinking about some preference edition which would allow me to use "<php" + enter and archieve what there should be

Answer (score 0):

Just type `php` and press enter, this will fix it.

Comment: Not really. It just write "php" and moves me to the next line.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't change a setting? For me it works that way. Otherwise you can try to create a snippet like described here: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/auto-complete-php-tag/8623/2

Comment: Try pressing ctrl space